# Is there Azure equivalent to Amazon AWS Slack notifications?

Tags: c#, azure, slack

In AWS I have code, which is used to send Slack notifications as following:

```cs
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;
..................
var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(); // connect using network creds
var request = new PublishRequest(slackTopicArn, message);
var response = await client.PublishAsync(request);
```

This provides a simple, concise way to send Slack messages.

Is there an Azure functionality similar to this, or I must use web client with Slack URL??

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Bot Service?

Comment: @GauravMantri is there a c# nuget library for that?

Comment: @GauravMantri this one `Azure.ResourceManager.BotService` ?

Comment: Search for Bot Framework SDK please. `Azure.ResourceManager.BotService` is managing the Bot Service itself. However, I do not think it would be as easy as the code you mentioned.

Comment: @GauravMantri At this point I don't see how Bot Framework can help my application to send Slack notification. Even if I created a bot, it would need to call slack to do same thing.

Comment: But that's just all a framework.  There must be something configured in SNS to say it goes to Slack.  Is that a standard thing or is the message simply routing to a lambda (or something) that then on sends the message to Slack?  Also, what's your definition of a "Slack notification"?  Is that just a message to a channel?

Comment: @Skin I don't know what was configured on the network. Yes, this is a message to a channel. In the code, this is simple SNS call provided by AWS SDK. See- it passes Arn and the message itself, and does publishing, But I don't see anything like this SDK for Azure.

Comment: There a hundred ways to skin a cat here, two of which are … send the channel an email or use PowerAutomate/LogicApps. You’re missing the point, the code you’ve provided is the tip of the ice berg, there’s configuration behind that (might be a lambda?!?) which is doing work. Azure has the same kind of services which serve the same purpose. A queuing service in Azure will give you the same amount of lines give or take but again, that’s just the tip of the iceberg. Using PowerAutomate is zero lines of code but to invoke the flow, you’d literally just need to make a POST call to a url.

Comment: @Skin Makes sense. Then again, POST to URL with payload will be just a normal call to HttpClient. Something that `AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient` wraps for me. Right? This is like in Redis. I can use .NET SDK or I can make RAW calls.